# excel formulas for if condition

Tags: excel, formula

i have 2 column with different values

```
5000    99999
2500    2000
1000    500
        0
        0
        999999
        0
        500
```

if in first column value is greater than second then print the excess amount in third column otherwise zero

how can i do this in EXCEL please suggest

Comment: 5000 99999 0 2500 2000 500 1000 500 0 200 0 200 75 50 25 999999 0 500 i want to output just like in third column

Comment: please edit your question, instead posting your data in comments

Answer (score 3):

Just use this simple formula:

```
=MAX(A1-B1,0)
```

Comment: Like the use of the Max formula instead of an if statement (either will do but this is much more simple^^)

Comment: Simple formula, Advance logic. :)